# Avoiding getting css style with page using InnerHTML

Tags: html, css, ajax, innerhtml

using the code below, by clicking a link in my nav menu, i get an html page in a certain div (InnerHTML), but, i have my menu il css style, and after clicking a link and getting the page to the div , it seems that my nav li css is corrupted and gets the css style of the page i clicket and got within the div... how can i avoid getting the css with the page im requesting please demonstrate me, i cant find something related.
thank you.

```
<script>
function processAjax(url) { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Non-IE browsers 
      req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
      req.onreadystatechange = targetDiv; 
      try { 
        req.open("GET", url, true); 
      } catch (e) { 
        alert(e); 
      } 
      req.send(null); 
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 
      req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
      if (req) { 
        req.onreadystatechange = targetDiv; 
        req.open("GET", url, true); 
        req.send(); 

      } 
    } 
  return false; 
} 
function targetDiv() { 
    if (req.readyState == 4) { // Complete 
          if (req.status == 200) { // OK response 
              document.getElementById("containerDiv").innerHTML = req.responseText;

          } else { 
            alert("Problem: " + req.statusText); 
          } 
    } 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Are there elements with `style` attributes?

Comment: you mean for example in one page that i'm getting to my div? if you do then i have style element only between the style tags within the head tags in the page im requsting, no style elements within the body tags.

Comment: The only reason the imported HTML should be bringing its own styles with it is if there are elements with `style` *attributes* (such as, for example: `<p style="font-size: 2em; background-color: #f00;`>...</p>`, and such-like).

Comment: Element in the html page that imported? Because i double checked it and it is clean from this way of stylish which means that this is not the problam..

Comment: And by the way, can you please tell me what code i need to add in order to refresh the whole website page by every click that imports me html page (for seo reasons)